# Cell in List with LazyVGrid Disappears sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios15

I have this:

```
        VStack {            
            List {
                LazyVGrid(columns: gridItemLayout) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.objects, id: \.fileGroupUUID) { item in
                        AlbumItemsScreenCell(object: item, viewModel: viewModel, config: Self.config)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                switch viewModel.changeMode {
                                case .moving, .sharing, .moveAll:
                                    viewModel.toggleItemToChange(item: item)
                                case .none:
                                    object = item
                                    viewModel.showCellDetails = true
                                }
                            }
                            .onLongPressGesture {
                                viewModel.restartDownload(fileGroupUUID: item.fileGroupUUID)
                            }
                    } // end ForEach
                } // end LazyVGrid
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .refreshable {
                viewModel.refresh()
            }
            .padding(5)
            // Mostly this is to animate updates from the menu. E.g., the sorting order.
            .animation(.easeInOut)
            
            // Had a problem with return animation for a while: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65101561
            // The solution was to take the NavigationLink out of the scrollview/LazyVGrid above.
            if let object = object {
                // The `NavigationLink` works here because the `MenuNavBar` contains a `NavigationView`.
                NavigationLink(
                    destination:
                        ObjectDetailsView(object: object, model: ObjectDetailsModel(object: object)),
                    isActive:
                        $viewModel.showCellDetails) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                .disabled(true)
            } // end if
        } // end VStack
```

AlbumItemsScreenCell:

```
struct AlbumItemsScreenCell: View {
    @StateObject var object:ServerObjectModel
    @StateObject var viewModel:AlbumItemsViewModel
    let config: IconConfig
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    var body: some View {
        AnyIcon(model: AnyIconModel(object: object), config: config,
            emptyUpperRightView: viewModel.changeMode == .none,
            upperRightView: {
                UpperRightChangeIcon(object: object, viewModel: viewModel)
            })
    }
}
```

When a user taps one of the cells, this causes navigation to a details screen. Sometimes when the user returns from that navigation, the cell in the upper left disappears:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mi6j2ie7h8dcdm0/disappearingCell.mp4?dl=0

My current hypothesis about the issue is that when user actions in that details screen take actions which change `viewModel.objects`, this causes the disappearing cell problem. I'll be testing this hypothesis shortly.

----- Update, 11/1/21 ------

Well, that hypothesis was wrong. I now understand the structure of the problem more clearly. Still don't have a fix though.

Tapping on one of the `AlbumItemsScreenCell`s navigates to a details screen (I've added to the code above to show that). In the details screen user actions can cause a comment count to get reset, which sends a `Notification`.

A model in the `AlbumItemsScreenCell` listens for these notification (for the specific cell) and resets a badge on the cell.

Here is that model:

```
class AnyIconModel: ObservableObject, CommentCountsObserverDelegate, MediaItemBadgeObserverDelegate, NewItemBadgeObserverDelegate {
    @Published var mediaItemBadge: MediaItemBadge?
    @Published var unreadCountBadgeText: String?
    @Published var newItem: Bool = false
    var mediaItemCommentCount:CommentCountsObserver!
    let object: ServerObjectModel
    var mediaItemBadgeObserver: MediaItemBadgeObserver!
    var newItemObserver: NewItemBadgeObserver!
    
    init(object: ServerObjectModel) {
        self.object = object
        
        // This is causing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69783232/cell-in-list-with-lazyvgrid-disappears-sometimes
        mediaItemCommentCount = CommentCountsObserver(object: object, delegate: self)
        
        mediaItemBadgeObserver = MediaItemBadgeObserver(object: object, delegate: self)
        newItemObserver = NewItemBadgeObserver(object: object, delegate: self)
    }
}
```

The `unreadCountBadgeText` gets changed (on the main thread) by the observer when the `Notification` is received.

So, in summary, the badge on the cell gets changed while the screen with the cells is not displayed-- the details screen is displayed.

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? Otherwise, it is impossible for anyone to run your code and try to help debug it.

Comment: looks like your 2 `@StateObject` in  `AlbumItemsScreenCell` should probably be `@ObservedObject`. Once you show us a minimal reproducible example, we'll know more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I had been using the following conditional modifier:

```
extension View {
    public func enabled(_ enabled: Bool) -> some View {
        return self.disabled(!enabled)
    }
    
    // https://forums.swift.org/t/conditionally-apply-modifier-in-swiftui/32815/16
    @ViewBuilder func `if`<T>(_ condition: Bool, transform: (Self) -> T) -> some View where T : View {
        if condition {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

to display the badge on the `AlbumItemsScreenCell`.

The original badge looked like this:

```
extension View {
    func upperLeftBadge(_ badgeText: String) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(UpperLeftBadge(badgeText))
    }
}

struct UpperLeftBadge: ViewModifier {
    let badgeText: String
    init(_ badgeText: String) {
        self.badgeText = badgeText
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(
                ZStack {
                    Badge(badgeText)
                }
                .padding([.top, .leading], 5),
                alignment: .topLeading
            )
    }
}
```

i.e., the usage looked like this in the cell:

```
        .if(condition) {
            $0.upperLeftBadge(badgeText)
        }
```

when I changed the modifier to use it with out this `.if` modifier, and used it directly, the issue went away:

```
extension View {
    func upperLeftBadge(_ badgeText: String?) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(UpperLeftBadge(badgeText: badgeText))
    }
}

struct UpperLeftBadge: ViewModifier {
    let badgeText: String?

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(
                ZStack {
                    if let badgeText = badgeText {
                        Badge(badgeText)
                    }
                }
                .padding([.top, .leading], 5),
                alignment: .topLeading
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may sounds weird, but in my tvOS app i disable the animations
and cells(Views) stops to disappear
So try to remove `.animation(.easeInOut)`